# Python tkinter, do something before subprocess starts

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

I'm really having a problem with my Python tkinter program. Basically all I want to do is to press a button to start a subprocess and indicate that the subprocess is running by changing a label's value. The subprocess takes some time and the problem is that the label always waits for the subprocess to be finished to change, which I don't understand, because I used a variable to first change the label and then go on with the subprocess. Here is the code:

```
def program_final():
    start = False
    while True:
        if start == False: 
            v.set("scanning...")
            label.pack()
            start = True
        else:
            # p = subprocess.Popen('sudo nfc-poll', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)     # opens a subporocess which starts nfc-polling in background
            p = subprocess.Popen('ping 8.8.8.8', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            counter = 0
            output = ""
            lines = []
            while True:
                line = p.stdout.readline() # this while loop iterates through the output lines of the 
                lines.insert(counter, line) # subproccess and saves the whole result into a list
                counter = counter +1 # the result will be needed to set output
                if counter == 9:
                    break

            if lines[6][7:10] == 'UID': # check if UID line is present
                output = output + "Tag found!\n" + lines[6][7:] # if yes the output string gets added the UID of the tag
            elif lines[6][7:10] != 'UID': # if the UID line is not present which means no tag is found
                output = output + "No tag found!\n" # the output is set to no tag found

            text.delete(1.0, END) # old tag infos are getting deleted out of texfield
            text.insert(INSERT, output) # tag infos or 'no tag found' message is added to the textfield
            break
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter update graphic only when there is nothing else to do. You can force the GUI to refresh if you use the update method on the widgets you really want to update.

```
tk.updates()
```